# CDK: There are no 'Private' subnet groups in this VPC after private group is deployed

Tags: java, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk

I have deployed rivate subnets in default vpc (java):

```
var stack = new Stack(app, "system-resource", StackProps.builder().env(env).build());
final IVpc vpc = Vpc.fromLookup(stack, "default-vpc", VpcLookupOptions.builder().isDefault(true).build());
final AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
var zones = stack.getAvailabilityZones();
var subnets = zones.stream().map(z -> {
  var subnet = new PrivateSubnet(stack, "priavte-subnet-" + index.getAndIncrement(), PrivateSubnetProps.builder()
      .vpcId(vpc.getVpcId())
      .cidrBlock(String.format(cidrTemplate, start.get()))
      .availabilityZone(z)
      .build());
  start.addAndGet(increment);
  return subnet;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then I tried to use SubnetSelection:

```
final IVpc vpc = Vpc.fromLookup(this, "default-vpc", VpcLookupOptions.builder().isDefault(true).build());
final SubnetSelection vpcSubnets = SubnetSelection.builder().subnetType(SubnetType.PRIVATE).build();
```

And got exception:

```
An exception occured while executing the Java class. There are no 'Private' subnet groups in this VPC. Available types: Public
```

[ERROR] Error: There are no 'Private' subnet groups in this VPC. Available types: Public

How it determine a VPC to select from?

Why all my PrivateSubnets which had created before are "marketed" as public and can no be selected?

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I was using a VPC created in CDK itself with only ISOLATED subnets.

```
const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'private_vpc', {
    subnetConfiguration: [
        {
            name: 'application-subnet',
            subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
        }
    ]
});
```

I got this error when I tried to create a StepFunction task for ECS.

```
    const task = new sfnTasks.EcsRunTask(this, 'my_task', {
        integrationPattern: sfn.IntegrationPattern.WAIT_FOR_TASK_TOKEN,
        containerOverrides: [{
                containerDefinition: myContainerDefinition,
        }],
        cluster,mytextExtractionTaskDefinition,
        launchTarget: new sfnTasks.EcsFargateLaunchTarget(),
        securityGroups: [vpcSecurityGroup],
    });
```

The fix was to specify the subnets explicitly.

```
    const subnets = vpc.selectSubnets({
        subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED
    }).subnets;

    const task = new sfnTasks.EcsRunTask(this, 'my_task', {
        integrationPattern: sfn.IntegrationPattern.WAIT_FOR_TASK_TOKEN,
        containerOverrides: [{
                containerDefinition: myContainerDefinition,
        }],
        cluster,mytextExtractionTaskDefinition,
        launchTarget: new sfnTasks.EcsFargateLaunchTarget(),
        subnets: subnets, // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
        securityGroups: [vpcSecurityGroup],
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

fromLookup method used to find an existing (already deployed) VPC in your account, when you define a VPC in CDK code you need to use the object you just created.

[see docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.Vpc.html#:%7E:text=the%20placement%20strategy.-,static%20fromLookup(scope%2C%20id%2C%20options),-public%20static%20fromLookup):

> **static fromLookup(scope, id, options)** Import an existing VPC from by querying the AWS environment this stack is deployed to.
>
> This function only needs to be used to use VPCs not defined in your
> CDK application. If you are looking to share a VPC between stacks, you
> can pass the Vpc object between stacks and use it as normal.